# May non-principal ideals have principal intersection and sum?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $\mathbf{R}$ be a ring with unit $1$.
Let $I, J$ be ideals of $\mathbf{R}$ such that $I \cap J = (a)$ and $I + J = (b)$, for some $a, b \in R$.
(Here, $(x)$ means the principal ideal generated by $x$.)
Does it follow that $I$ and $J$ are principal ideals?

In case it doesn't, what about the specific case in which $a=0$ and $b=1$ (so that $I \cap J = \{0\}$ and $I+J = R$)?

Comment: In the second case $R/J\simeq I$, so $I$ (and also $J$) is principal.

Comment: @user26857 Is this obvious? Is the quotient of a ring by an ideal always isomorphic to a principal ideal?

Comment: The quotient $R/J$ is a cyclic $R$-module, and so is $I$.

Comment: Thanks for your attention @user26857. So $R/J = (I + J) / J \cong I / ( I \cap J) \cong I$, where the first isomorphism is by one of the isomorphism theorems for rings, but I still don't see why is $I$ a principal ideal. Of course that will follow from $R/J$ being cyclic, so that $I$ is generated by $\phi(x)$ where $\phi$ is an isomorphism from $R/J$ to $I$, and $x$ is a generator of the cyclic module $R/J$, right? But why is $R/J$ cyclic?

Comment: $R/J$ (as $R$-module) is generated by $1$.

Comment: A counterexample for the general case: let $P_1,P_2$ be two non-principal prime ideals in a Dedekind domain such that $P_1P_2$ is principal. Set $I=P_1^2P_2$ and $J=P_1P_2^2$. Then $I+J=P_1P_2$ and $I\cap J=P_1^2P_2^2$.

Comment: @user26857 Thanks! You might just gather all that and put it in an answer, since you've got it all :)